# How can I see the intermediate updates on my UI while debugging iPad code?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am developing an app in which I am using a plist file. There are 21 key-value pairs in the plist. Each pair is a dictionary (type) with 6 items. The dictionary contains a set of images. In my program, I am using the path to retrieve the images. My requirement is that the images should be displayed one-by-one on the `imageView`. i have done it successfully. The images are being dispalyed exactly from plist.

So my question is can I use the debugger to see the intermediate execution of the plist? When I placed breakpoints in my code, and run using the debugger, I am able to step into the code and the images are displayed on the view only after the whole execution of plist with 21 key-value pairs is done. How can I see the images on the view *while* debugging each pair?

```
(void)setSequenceInfo:(NSDictionary *)sequenceInfo
{
    [self.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    self.sequenceQueue = [NSMutableArray array];

    //load the sequenceinfo dictionary
    [_sequenceInfo release];

    if (!sequenceInfo)
       return;

    _sequenceInfo = [sequenceInfo retain];

    //create one UIImageView by sequence
    NSMutableDictionary* views = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:[sequenceInfo count]];
    for (NSString* identifier in _sequenceInfo)
    {
        UIImageView* seqView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        seqView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        seqView.contentMode = self.contentMode;

        //the image is hidden until its sequence is played
        seqView.hidden=YES;
        //add the newly created image view to our subviews
        [self addSubview:seqView];
        //also store it in our sequenceViews dictionary
        [views setValue:seqView forKey:identifier];

        [seqView release];
    }
    self.sequenceViews = views;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to "see" intermediate results while using  the debugger, you'll have to change the structure of your code to return to the main run loop, so that the UIImageView has the chance to run and display the new image.   You could set up a timer that fires periodically, and in the timer routine you change the UIImageView's image to the next one in the sequence.  Then you set your breakpoint in the timer handler method in gdb, and when you hit that breakpoint each time you should see the previously displayed image.

EDIT: here's some more detail, based on what I think you want to do.   Realize, though, that I think there's no "magic wand" to be able to see changes on the screen while you're in the debugger.   You have to return to the Run Loop so that your UIKIt widgets get cycles to draw themselves.

For example, say you have this method:

```
- (void) updateTwoLabels:(NSString *)newText
{
    self.label1.text = newText;
    self.label2.text = newText;  // put breakpoint on this line
}
```

and you want to stop in the debugger just before label2's text is set, and see that label1 has changed.   Well, I think there's no way of doing that, except by modifying your code, and calling yourself again with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: so that the main run loop can run for a while then call your code again:

```
BOOL callAgain = NO;
BOOL setLabel2 = YES;
- (void) updateTwoLabels:(NSString *)newText
{
    self.label1.text = newText;
    if ( setLabel2 )
        self.label2.text = newText;  // put breakpoint on this line
    if ( callAgain )
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateTwoLabels:) withObject:newText afterDelay:0];
}
```

in this way, when you're debugging, you can set callAgain to YES and setLabel2 to NO in gdbg, and keep "continuing" until you see that label1 has changed.   That's the basic technique.

Comment: thanx a lot Bogatyr. i am new to programming. can u help with some code or an example code which meets my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Do the whole method in a background thread but call GUI stuff on the main thread. For example: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(addSubview:) withObject:seqView waitUntilDone:YES]. Don't forget to make an autorelease pool at the beginning of the method (the one that runs in the background thread) and drain it at the end of it.